# How to change excerpt length from characters to word

Tags: wordpress

I recently bought a new Wordpress theme but all my custom excerpts are being cut-off based on character count rather than word count. I've found the excerpt.php file that the theme is using and I think the issue down comes down to the use of substr, but I can't figure out how to change it to fix it. I tried replacing it with wp_trim_words but then I just saw a number rather than text in my excerpts.

Would be grateful if someone can point me in the right direction!

The code:

$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

```
if ( ! empty( $excerpt ) ) {
    $excerpt_length = healthfirst_get_search_page_excerpt_length();
    $new_excerpt    = ( $excerpt_length > 0 ) ? substr( $excerpt, 0, intval( $excerpt_length ) ) : $excerpt;
    ?>
    <p itemprop="description" class="qodef-e-excerpt">
        <?php echo esc_html( strip_tags( strip_shortcodes( $new_excerpt ) ) ); ?>
    </p>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace this line..

```
$new_excerpt    = ( $excerpt_length > 0 ) ? substr( $excerpt, 0, intval( $excerpt_length ) ) : $excerpt;
```

.. with.

```
$new_excerpt    = wp_trim_words( $excerpt, 10 );
```

You do not need the condition since you are trying to override the excerpt length. You can actually remove this line afterwards.

```
$excerpt_length = healthfirst_get_search_page_excerpt_length();
```

Unless it is still used somewhere else in that file or function.

Comment: Thank you so much! All fixed now

Comment: No problem Lisa. Glad to be of help. Take care.